# javascript preload image array keep requesting image

Tags: javascript

I have a preload function that makes an array with the source of some images.

```
function preload() {
  for (var n = 0; n < urls.length; n++) {
      images[n] = new Image;
      images[n].onload = updateCurrenttype();
      images[n].src = urls[n];
      console.log('urlsPreload[n]: '+urls[n]);
  }
}

function updateCurrenttype() {
currenttype = 1;
 }
```

The update current type function, should be like a flag to check if the image should be requested or not. But obviously is not working as intended :D

Then I have a show function to display the images, but for some reason which I can't see, the images keep been requested again and again. Instead of using the ones in the preload array.

```
function showimage() {
if (currenttype != 0) {
    imageitem.src = images[currentindex].src;
}
    console.log('urls[ci]:'+images[currentindex].src);
}
```

These images are an animation, so instead of downloading the images again and again I would like them to be reuse.

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the body of `updateCurrenttype()` as well ?

Comment: I think it depend on your configuration for caching image of your sever. try to set header to caching

Comment: @mohkhan updateCurenttype() posted.

Comment: Can you use images[n] array instead of using the src attribute ?
    `imageitem = images[currentindex];`